# On differentiating $F(x)=\ln(2x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If we differentiate $F(x)=\ln(2x)$ we will get $F'(x) =\dfrac2{2x}$ after the shortcut $F'(x)=\dfrac1x$, right?

Now if we integrate $F'(x)$ we will get $F(x)=\ln(x)$ but also $F(x)=\ln(2x)$. This means $\ln(2x)=\ln(x)$. What happened?

Comment: Antiderivatives are same upto [constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_integration).

Answer (score 3):

When you integrate, there is an arbitrary constant $C$ added. So you only get
$$\ln(2x)=\ln(x)+C.$$

Comment: this is exactly right Bjorn, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

But$$F(x)=\ln(2x) =\ln 2 + \ln x$$
So when you integrate back you get $$\ln x + C $$
where the constant $C$ should be the $\ln 2$ term.

Comment: This is exactly right, Ahmad Thanks. With recpect

Comment: im glad it was helpful @OsaidIbrahimBaniSalman

Answer (score 2):

The antiderivatives of $1/x$ are not uniquely determined ! They are given by

$$\ln x +C.$$

Forthermore $ \ln (2x)= \ln 2 + \ln x.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: This is true. Yes i can. Thanks

Comment: On a connected domain at least.